# Can all proof systems be generically described?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

Can every proof calculus (e.g. natural deduction, Hilbert-style axiomatic systems, sequent calculus) be expressed as a generic 4-tuple *{A, Ω, Z, I}* consisting of: set alpha of proposition symbols, omega set of operator symbols, zeta set of inference rules and iota set of axioms?

If yes, does it mean that, in principle, all syntax can be abstracted away and all proofs can be expressed as syllogisms of the form?:

```
 1. ...
 2. ...
 ...
 N. ...
 ∴ ...
```

Comment: See e.g. [Abstract consequence relations](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-algebraic-propositional/#AbstConsRela)

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA: Thanks for the citation, as I didn't realize this was a subtopic there. I think I'll use this citation somewhere the next time I revise my [generalized topology essay](https://mathoverflow.net/a/343400/15780) (search-in-page for "consequence operator"). FYI, I've been making a lot of minor edits and additions from time to time to my ASCII copy of all three parts, and at some later time (when it seems there are a sufficient number of edits/additions to merit an answer edit) I'll include the edits/additions.

Comment: Related to what @Mauro ALLEGRANZA gave, see also the Mathematics Stack Exchange question [Properties of the deductive closure](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1279969/13130).

Answer (score 2):

How would e.g. Smullyan-style tableaux proofs ("truth trees") fit into that picture?

Indeed, how would Gentzen-style natural deduction with its non-linear proof trees fit into the picture?

And what on earth is meant by talking of "syllogisms" here?

It is very unclear what insights could be gained by over-abstraction of *this* kind.

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong with this question per se. It is obvious that all those systems cannot be described in this way? If yes, why? How are then those systems compared? I'm trying to gain some insight how, fundamentally, they differ from each other. Wouldn't the task be simpler if we could describe them generically? Please excuse me if the question seems silly, but I'm a novice to the subject.

Comment: What I meant by "syllogism" was linear sequence of transformations from the premise to the conclusion by application of inference rules and axioms.